# How to use find the Lagrange Multipliers in multidimensional Calculus of Variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

Suppose I wish to minimise the integral

$$I = \int_{s_0}^{s_1}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}F\, dt ds$$

Where $F$ is a function of the six variables $x(s,t)$, $y(s,t)$, and their four partial derivatives, ie

$$F = F(x(s,t),y(s,t),x_s(s,t),x_t(s,t),y_s(s,t),y_t(s,t))$$

Subject to the constraint

$$G = 0$$

for all $s$ and $t$, where $G$ is also a function of those six variables.

As far as I understand, I construct $L=F-\lambda G$, and turn the machinery of Variational Calculus (ie the Euler-Lagrange equation) to minimising

$$J = \int_{s_0}^{s_1}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}L\, dt ds$$

If we apply the Euler Lagrange Equations

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_t}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_s}\right) = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$$

and similarly for $y$ and $\lambda$, we get two second order equations for $x$ and $y$ and reclaim $G=0$.  Suppose that the second order equations are not analytically solvable.  How do I determine $\lambda$?

In addition, how does this enforce $G=0$.  Surely if, for example, $\lambda>0$, then a solution which makes $G$ very negative (and hence also $L$) would prevail as one that minimises the integral of $L$?  Do we need to require that $G>0$ as part of our formulation of $G$ (by, for example, squaring it)?

Comment: The way you constructed $J$, it only enforces $\int G = 0$ (since the derivative with respect to $\lambda$ is zero at a critical point). To enforce pointwise constraint, you'll need a second PDE, namely the one coming from the variation $G(x+\delta x,\dots)-G(x,\dots)=0$. So, you will have an Euler-Lagrange equation for $I$, plus a PDE coming from $G=0$.

Comment: Won't I have too many equations then?  I'll have the two second orders for $x$ and $y$, and then another PDE?  Is it not possible to simply get two second orders that preserve $G=0$?